# Is it bad or good practice to store info on an object as an attribute of that object?

Tags: r, attributes

I have written code with many data tables and other objects. When other people need to look into my code, they often have no idea what the difference is between the different data tables I have created. I was therefore wondering whether it is advised to simply store a description of a particular data table as an attribute of that data table.

For example:

```
animal = c('rabbit', 'dog', 'cat')
food   = c('carrot', 'bone', 'fish')
DT     = data.table(animal, food)
attr(DT, 'information') <- 'table that holds info on what different animals eat'
attributes(DT)$information
```

Comment: why not just add comments to your code?

Comment: @Omry Atia, the same object is used in many different scripts. To explain via comments, this would mean that in every script I use an object, I have to explain it again unless the person who is looking at the code is willing to go to the script the object was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could argue that this question is asking for opintion, but before anyone leaps in with that, let's look at the code that already endorses the use of attributes for this purpose. The `comment` function exist for bot setting and getting such an attribute. The `comment` functions help page is entitled: "Query or Set a "comment" Attribute".

Frank Harrell's Hmisc package also has a `label` function that attaches informative strings to dataframe columns, as well as a `Label" function that does hte same to the dataframe itself.

Opinion supported by evidence: following Frank's lead in programming practice is "good".