# Create a value associated with a member of each list and store it with that member in R

Tags: r, list, function, dplyr, terra

I have a list of many dataframes, all of the same format. For each member of this list, I would like to generate a spatial extent, and store it with that dataframe (this data is all lat/long data, and I am using functions from the terra package to analyze it). I am not super experienced with working with lists, and so I took the following stab at trying to generate it:

```
library(terra)
library(dplyr)


lat_1 <- c(23.2, 14.5, 28.6)
lon_1 <- c(12.1, 8.5, 2.2)

lat_2 <- c(89.3, 94.4, 72.3)
lon_2 <- c(45.2, 47, 48.5)

coords_1 <- data.frame(lon_1, lat_1)
coords_2 <- data.frame(lon_2, lat_2)

list_coords <- list(coords_1, coords_2)

write_extent <- function(lon, lat) {
  max_lat <- ceiling(max(lat)) 
  min_lat <- floor(min(lat)) 
  max_lon <- ceiling(max(lon)) 
  min_lon <- floor(min(lon))
  extent <- extent(x = c(max_lat, min_lat, max_lon, min_lon))
}
```

However, this function has errors, and I can't conceptualize how I can store the spatial extent that corresponds with each member of the list with that specific list- should I be using mutate()? Should I not be designing a function and rather be using lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  First, you'll want to make the data frames have the same column names for longitude and latitude `lon` and `lat`, but that's arbitrary.  Once you've done that, then one way is to produce a new list where each element of the list has both a data frame and an extent object:

```r
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)


lat_1 <- c(23.2, 14.5, 28.6)
lon_1 <- c(12.1, 8.5, 2.2)

lat_2 <- c(89.3, 94.4, 72.3)
lon_2 <- c(45.2, 47, 48.5)

coords_1 <- data.frame(lon = lon_1, lat = lat_1)
coords_2 <- data.frame(lon = lon_2, lat = lat_2)

list_coords <- list(coords_1, coords_2)

write_extent <- function(lon, lat) {
  max_lat <- ceiling(max(lat)) 
  min_lat <- floor(min(lat)) 
  max_lon <- ceiling(max(lon)) 
  min_lon <- floor(min(lon))
  extent <- extent(x = min_lat, xmax=max_lat, ymin = min_lon, ymax=max_lon)
  extent
}

res <- lapply(list_coords, function(x){
  list(data=x, extent = write_extent(x$lon, x$lat))
})
res
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$data
#>    lon  lat
#> 1 12.1 23.2
#> 2  8.5 14.5
#> 3  2.2 28.6
#> 
#> [[1]]$extent
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 14 
#> xmax       : 29 
#> ymin       : 2 
#> ymax       : 13 
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$data
#>    lon  lat
#> 1 45.2 89.3
#> 2 47.0 94.4
#> 3 48.5 72.3
#> 
#> [[2]]$extent
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 72 
#> xmax       : 95 
#> ymin       : 45 
#> ymax       : 49
```

In the output above, you could get the data for the first object with `res[[1]]$data` and the extent for the first object with `res[[1]]$extent`.    Or you could get a list of all the extents with `lapply(res, function(x)x$extent)`.  Another option would be to store the extent as an attribute of the data.  This way, it always follows the data around:

```r
res <- lapply(list_coords, function(x){
  e <- write_extent(x$lon, x$lat)
  attr(x, "extent") <- e
  x
})
res
#> [[1]]
#>    lon  lat
#> 1 12.1 23.2
#> 2  8.5 14.5
#> 3  2.2 28.6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    lon  lat
#> 1 45.2 89.3
#> 2 47.0 94.4
#> 3 48.5 72.3
```

You don't see the extent when you print the data frame, but you can retrieve it either for a single data frame with:

```r
attr(res[[1]], "extent")
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 14 
#> xmax       : 29 
#> ymin       : 2 
#> ymax       : 13
```

Or for all of them with:

```r
lapply(res, function(x)attr(x, "extent"))
#> [[1]]
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 14 
#> xmax       : 29 
#> ymin       : 2 
#> ymax       : 13 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> class      : Extent 
#> xmin       : 72 
#> xmax       : 95 
#> ymin       : 45 
#> ymax       : 49
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

While I think it's a bit less conventional to set object attributes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872572/is-it-bad-or-good-practice-to-store-info-on-an-object-as-an-attribute-of-that-ob) suggests it is not bad practice to do so.

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful response! It really gets at how these lists are functioning fundamentally.